# Get more than 8 images in Listview

Tags: android, google-image-search

```
 public class getImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
       JSONObject json;
       ProgressDialog dialog;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onPreExecute();

           dialog = ProgressDialog.show(GoogleSearchAPIExampleActivity.this, "", "Please wait...");
       }

       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           URL url;
           try {
               url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +"v=1.0&q="+strSearch+"&rsz=8&start=0" );

           URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
           connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", "http://technotalkative.com");

           String line;
           StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
           while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               builder.append(line);
           }

           System.out.println("Builder string => "+builder.toString());

           json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           if(dialog.isShowing())
           {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }

           try 
           {
               JSONObject responseObject = json.getJSONObject("responseData");
               JSONArray resultArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");

               listImages = getImageList(resultArray);
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Length :" + listImages.size(), 5000).show();
              // SetListViewAdapter(listImages);


               System.out.println("Result array length => "+resultArray.length());
               Intent in = new Intent(GoogleSearchAPIExampleActivity.this, Second.class);
               startActivity(in);
           } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }
   }
```

Above is the code to get images using google image api. But here I get only 8 images for 1 search. What needs to be done if I want to get more than 8 images?

Comment: what does "&rsz=8" do in the URL you are creating? seems like a prime candidate to check out

Comment: It is the number of images I get, but when I change it to 10 or more, nothing is the output

Comment: @thumbernirmal : means api return only 8 images per page so you also need to add start param to make next request from 8 images

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: ya I know that like,
url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +"v=1.0&q="+strSearch+"&rsz=8&start=8" ); will give next 8 images, but I don't know how to add them...

Answer (score 0):

continuing my comment above, docs state

```
rsz    rsz=4    This argument supplies an integer from 1–8 indicating the number of results to return per page.
```

so it seems like you're gonna have to page through the results on your own with new calls

read about the use of `cursor` [here](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide#basic)